# Getting a 'Field' object has no attribute 'vocab' error when trying to predict on a test set

Tags: python, pytorch, torchtext

Ive been successfully able to train models with my train data, but am having some trouble now predicting on my test data. So I am loading in by test data with

```
id1 = ttd.LabelField(use_vocab =False)
test_dataset= ttd.TabularDataset(
    path= 'test_1.csv',
    format='csv',
    skip_header=True,
    fields=[('id', id1),('text', TEXT)]
)
test_iter= ttd.BucketIterator(
    test_dataset_kaggle,
    batch_size=64,
    sort_key=lambda x: len(x.text),
    device=device)
```

and use the following function for prediction

```
def get_predictions_test(test_iter, model):
  model.eval()
  with torch.no_grad():
    predictions= np.array([])
    id2= np.array([])

    for batch in test_iter:
      output=model(batch.data)
      ##print(np.shape(output))
      ##print(output)
      y_pred_tag = np.squeeze(torch.round((output)))
      #_,indices = torch.max(output,dim=1)
      ##print(np.shape(predictions))
      ##print(np.shape(y_pred_tag))
      predictions=np.concatenate((predictions,y_pred_tag.cpu().numpy()))
      ##print(predictions)
      ##y_test = np.concatenate((y_test,batch.label.cpu().numpy()))
      id2 = np.concatenate((id2,batch.id.cpu().numpy()))
      
  return id2, predictions
```

However, when I try to run

```
id4, predictions = get_predictions_test(test_iter,rnn_model)
```

I get the error 'Field' object has no attribute 'vocab'. I already built a vocab for TEXT so that shouldn't be the problem. Am I supposed to build a vocab for ID? Or is there something else I am doing wrong

Comment: Yes you have to.